# How to disable prefixes in Emotion 11 in development?

Tags: reactjs, emotion, autoprefixer

In Emotion versions previous to 11 I used to disable CSS prefixing in development like this:

```js
const emotionCache = createCache({
  prefix: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : true,
})
```

Now [the prefixer is a plugin of the Stylis parser](https://emotion.sh/docs/emotion-11#stylis-v4) and the `prefix` option has been removed.
They say you can copy  and paste the plugin code if you want to customise it. But all I want is just to disable it in development.

Is there a clean way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an [answer from the emotion developers](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2212).

It's possible to disable all Stylis plugins – including the auto-prefixer – like this:

```js
const emotionCache = createCache({
  key: 'your-key',
  ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && { stylisPlugins: [] }),
})
```

Comment: More info: https://emotion.sh/docs/cache-provider