# Material UI disable browser specific CSS rules --webkit- etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I would like to disable all of the browser rules that are exported when MUI is compiled[image]:

So I would like to see:

```
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

This

```
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

I cannot see a way to do this with MUI4 or MUI5.

### Component

```
import React from 'react'
import { styled } from '@mui/material'
    
const ChildContainer = styled('div')`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
`

export const TopNav: React.FC = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
      <ChildContainer data-name="ChildContainer">{children}</ChildContainer>
  )
}

export default TopNav
```

Comment: What about `width`?

Comment: I believe this is done by `emotion`, and they [dropped support](https://emotion.sh/docs/emotion-11#stylis-v4) for customising it in v11. The docs suggest to fork the prefixer plugin and customise it yourself.

Comment: Is this all in one file or seperate ones?

Comment: These are in the same file. I have added an example component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control this using Emotion's [CacheProvider component](https://emotion.sh/docs/cache-provider) by providing it with a cache that does not leverage the `prefixer` stylis plugin. Below is a working example that allows you to toggle back and forth between including the vendor prefixes or not.

```
import React from "react";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { prefixer } from "stylis";

const StyledDiv = styled("div")`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
`;
const cacheNoPrefixer = createCache({
  key: "noprefixer",
  stylisPlugins: []
});
const cacheWithPrefixer = createCache({
  key: "prefixer",
  stylisPlugins: [prefixer]
});

export default function App() {
  const [includePrefixer, setIncludePrefixer] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <CacheProvider
      value={includePrefixer ? cacheWithPrefixer : cacheNoPrefixer}
    >
      <StyledDiv>
        Including Prefixing: {JSON.stringify(includePrefixer)}
        <Button onClick={() => setIncludePrefixer(!includePrefixer)}>
          Toggle Prefixing
        </Button>
      </StyledDiv>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit no vendor-prefixing]

Related answers:

- [How to disable prefixes in Emotion 11 in development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717638/how-to-disable-prefixes-in-emotion-11-in-development)
- [Material-Ui TextField not affected with the RTL direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799638/material-ui-textfield-not-affected-with-the-rtl-direction/62802353#62802353) (a different usage of `CacheProvider`)

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. I wonder if there is a way to disable this on the root level. IE not with each individual styled-componet. I will be reading more into it :)

Comment: The root level is the only place you should do this. It affects the styles for all descendants of the CacheProvider element.

Comment: I am wondering how this will play with SSR too :D Time to find out!